# How to check a column with multi values

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables like
1:-Users

```
id  name
1   vivek
2   raj
3   mohan
4   gagan
5   priya
```

2:-Purchase

```
id  typee        user_id
1   class        1
2   class        1
3   course       1
4   class        2
5   test_series  3
6   test_series  2
```

I want to search those student who had purchase one from class or course and had purchased the test_series as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT u.name
FROM purchase p1
join users u on p1.user_id = u.id
join (select distinct user_id
      from purchase
      where typee = 'test_series') p2 on p1.user_id = p2.user_id
where typee in ('class', 'course')
GROUP BY user_id
having count(distinct typee) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below query :

```
SELECT p.id,
     SUM( IF( typeee = 'class' || typeee = 'course', 1,0) ) as tot,
     SUM( IF (typeee = 'test_series', 1,0) ) as classcourse
FROM purchasee as p
GROUP by p.user_id
```